React Native with expo SDK 52 Default Splash Screen and Icon
I have some problem with splash at expo project, when I want to render an image for the splash screen, what appears on the splash screen is an image for the icon. does anyone have the same problem? Heres my app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "projectName",
    "slug": "projectName",
    "version": "1.3.2",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/images/splash.png",
    "newArchEnabled": true,
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/images/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "cover"
    },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.kawan.projectname"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/images/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "d9867a6f-49d4-4482-a5e3-e1066db23ae1"
      }
    }
  }
}


Anyone can help? im so stuck, I just learned to make react native applications from expo. I think, I have followed all the documentation in the splash expo documentations section, and have also looked for other references, but none of them have the same case or problem.
And I have also tried to create a new component specifically for splashScreen but to disable the default splash screen from expo it can't, even though the way is to just delete expo.splash in app.json..

Did you find any solutions? I am facing same issue... I tried to downgrade sdk51 it does work I can see splash screen but app crashed due compatibility issues. I couldn't figure out on sdk52

I am facing the same problem.

There is some issue with splash screen image being named as "splash" and it does not recognise the new image. What you can do is instead of naming it as splash rename it as splash-something dot file extension.
For example: Change splash.png to splash-image.png and it worked in my case.
